# Get data in redis with part of a key in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis

I have these keys in my redis server with their data  :

```
AdminIpoChangeEntity:0
AdminIpoChangeEntity:1
AdminIpoChangeEntity:2
AdminIpoChangeEntity:3
```

I want to pass just `AdminIpoChangeEntity` to my method and my method should return four records .
Here is my redis repository :

```
 private IDatabase RedisDb => _connection.Value.GetDatabase();
    //

    private string Key(TEntity entity) => $"{typeof(TEntity).Name}:{entity.Id}";
    private string Key(string id) => $"{typeof(TEntity).Name}:{id}";

    public async Task<OperationResult> AddOrUpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
            var val = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(entity);
            var res = await RedisDb.StringSetAsync(Key(entity), val);

            return OperationResult<TEntity>.Succeed();
    }
   public async Task<OperationResult<TEntity>> GetByIdAsync(string id)
    {
            var value = await RedisDb.StringGetAsync(Key(id));
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TEntity>(value.ToString());
                return OperationResult<TEntity>.Succeed(result);
            }
            return OperationResult<TEntity>.Succeed(null);

    }
```

And I need this one :

```
public async Task<OperationResult<IList<TEntity>>> GetAllAsync()
{

        var value = await RedisDb.StringGetAsync(Key(nameof(TEntity)));

        throw new NotImplementedException();

}
```

My entity name is `AdminIpoChangeEntity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should find all keys that match with my value and after that pass them into getstring to find all values ,here is my final code :

```
public async Task<OperationResult<IList<TEntity>>> GetAllAsync()
{
    EndPoint endPoint = _connection.Value.GetEndPoints().First();
    RedisKey[] keys = _connection.Value.GetServer(endPoint).Keys(pattern: typeof(TEntity).Name+"*").ToArray();
    var value = await RedisDb.StringGetAsync(keys);
    if (value.Count()>0)
    {
      var result=  value.Select(d => System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TEntity>(d)).ToArray();
      //  var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IList<TEntity>>(value.ToString());
        return OperationResult<IList<TEntity>>.Succeed(result);
    }
    return OperationResult<IList<TEntity>>.Succeed(null);

}
```